# Problem with nested dictionaries that changes certain values for different adverts

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape links on a website. When I follow the link it can be either a motor advert or an ordinary advert.
The keys that I need to scrape for both types of adverts are the same:

For the Motor adverts - data = dict_keys['header', 'description', 'currency', 'price', 'wanted', 'id', 'photos', 'section', 'age', 'spotlight', 'year', 'state', 'friendlyUrl', 'keyInfo', 'seller', 'displayAttributes', 'countyTown', 'breadcrumbs']

For the Ordinary adverts - data = dict_keys(['header', 'description', 'currency', 'price', 'wanted', 'id', 'photos', 'section', 'age', 'spotlight', 'year', 'state', 'friendlyUrl', 'keyInfo', 'seller', 'displayAttributes', 'countyTown', 'breadcrumbs'])

In the Motor adverts data the 'breadcrumbs' key gives me

```
[{'name': 'motor',
  'displayName': 'Cars & Motor',
  'id': 1003,
  'title': 'Cars Motorbikes Trucks Caravans and More',
  'subdomain': 'www',
  'containsSubsections': True,
  'xtn2': 101},
 {'name': 'cars',
  'displayName': 'Cars',
  'id': 11,
  'title': 'Cars',
  'subdomain': 'cars',
  'containsSubsections': False,
  'xtn2': 142}]
```

while in the Ordinary adverts 'breadcrumbs' gives me

```
[{'name': 'all',
  'displayName': 'All Sections',
  'id': 2066,
  'title': 'See Everything For Sale',
  'subdomain': 'www',
  'containsSubsections': True,
  'xtn2': 100},
 {'name': 'household',
  'displayName': 'House & DIY',
  'id': 1001,
  'title': 'House & DIY',
  'subdomain': 'www',
  'containsSubsections': True,
  'xtn2': 105},
 {'name': 'furniture',
  'displayName': 'Furniture & Interiors',
  'id': 3,
  'title': 'Furniture',
  'subdomain': 'www',
  'containsSubsections': True,
  'xtn2': 105},
 {'name': 'kitchenappliances',
  'displayName': 'Kitchen Appliances',
  'id': 1089,
  'title': 'Kitchen Appliances',
  'subdomain': 'www',
  'containsSubsections': False,
  'xtn2': 105}]
```

I have tried to get the Motor data by calling the 'xtn2' key and value with data['breadcrumbs'][0]['xtn2'] == 101: and giving it a name 'motordata'

```
if data['breadcrumbs'][0]['xtn2'] == 101:
            motordata = data
            if motordata:
                motors = motordata['breadcrumbs'][0]['name']
                views = motordata['views']
                title = motordata['header']
                Adcounty = motordata['county']
                itemId = motordata['id']
                sellerId = motordata['seller']['id']
                sellerName = motordata['seller']['name']
                adCount = motordata['seller']['adCount']
                lifetimeAds = motordata['seller']['adCountStats']['lifetimeAdView']['value']
                currency = motordata['currency']
                price = motordata['price']
                adUrl = motordata['friendlyUrl']
                adAge = motordata['age']
                spotlight = motordata['spotlight']
```

and the Ordinary data with elif data['breadcrumbs'][0]['xtn2'] == 100: with a name 'Allotherads'

```
elif data['breadcrumbs'][0]['xtn2'] == 100:
            Allotherads = alldata
            if Allotherads:
                views = Allotherads['views']
                title = Allotherads['header']
                itemId = Allotherads['id']
                Adcounty = Allotherads['county']
                # Adtown = alldata['countyTown']
                sellerId = Allotherads['seller']['id']
                sellerName = Allotherads['seller']['name']
                adCount = Allotherads['seller']['adCount']
                lifetimeAds = Allotherads['seller']['adCountStats']['lifetimeAdView']['value']
                currency = Allotherads['currency']
                price = Allotherads['price']
                adUrl = Allotherads['friendlyUrl']
                adAge = Allotherads['age']
                spotlight = Allotherads['spotlight']
                topSectionName = Allotherads['xitiAdData']['topSectionName']
                xtn2 = Allotherads['breadcrumbs'][2]['xtn2']
                subSection = Allotherads['breadcrumbs'][2]['displayName']
```

but it doesn't work. It just scrapes the Ordinary adverts but not the Motor adverts.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do (if multiple motor dicts are possible):

```
motordata = [x for x in data.get('breadcrumbs') if x.get('name') == "motor"]
```

or (if only one motordata is possible:

```
motordata = next(iter([x for x in data.get('breadcrumbs') if x.get('name') == "motor"]))
```

`next(iter())` works here the same as `[0]` at the end but is faster

Comment: thanks  Andreas, yes the first one worked for me. I'm just learning how to code so forgive my mistakes. Also, if some of the values aren't there how do I get around this? e.g adAge = Allotherads['age']....sometimes there isn't a value. How do I alter my code so it returns None as a response?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, for dictionaries you can do this: dictionary.get('keyword', None) so in your case: motordata.get('adAge', None). .get() retrieves the value of a key in a dictionary. If you provide a second parameter, this parameter will be returned in case the dictionary does not have that key.